# Why didn't the Dominators take up Mick Rory, a non-metahuman, while taking up the Team Arrow?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash, arrow

In *The Flash*, s3e8 named [*Invasion!*](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Invasion!_(The_Flash)), it was shown at the end of the episode that the Dominators abducted the Team Arrow  with the purpose of

> gathering information from their minds about metahumans, using hallucination as a distraction, to help them complete a special "weapon". <sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion!_(Arrowverse)#Plot)</sup>

It was later concluded by Team Arrow in the following [conversation](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=172&t=30041):

> Wait. Maybe they didn't choose us at random.
>
> Maybe they chose us because we couldn't fight back
>
> Because **none of you are metahumans.**

Mick Rory is also not a meta; he has a vivid rough past which could be a competent source for the hallucination.

Still he was not abducted by the Dominators.

Why was it so? Did they assume he had no enough information on metahumans? I don't think this is a valid reason for we all know Rory is well versed with metas.

Was it because he was along with Supergirl? But that doesn't make a justifiable argument either as Oliver was also with Barry.

So, why did the Dominators not abduct the *non-metahuman*  Rory?

Comment: Note that they also didn't beam up Felicity. [My answer](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/65882/12783) addresses both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Both Mick Rory and Felicity Smoak ran into a building, keeping them out of reach of the teleportation beam

You're asking about Mick, but it's notable that the Dominators also did not take Felicity Smoak, a non-metahuman who had a history with all of the people who were captured and has worked extensively with S.T.A.R. Labs and Barry Allen (thus she would have been a valuable source of intel about metahumans).

The answer is the same for both of them. When Oliver and the others were captured, they were all standing out in the open. Felicity and Mick were together underneath an umbrella much closer to the building and then quickly ran into it once people were starting to be captured.

[image: The Flash Invasion!, Mick Rory and Felicity running into a building]

It seems that being off to the side and then inside the building made it impossible to be beamed up, unlike the others who were out in the open.

Answer (score 2):

Because he would have been an anachronism in their **shared** hallucination.

---

All of the others have shared history (obviously as they are all *Arrow* characters originally) but none of them do with Mick (who started on *The Flash*).

By keeping the hallucination, at least mostly, internally consistent would have re-inforced the illusion.

A good question would be how the Dominators **knew** to only take Team Arrow!

Comment: Thanks Paulie; however would he being an anarchy pose a serious problem? Ultimately, they all would work together to come out of the hallucination as they all remembered everything about their present lives; similarly, Mick would have remembered that he is a Legend and now works with Sara and Roy; so even though if he started being a goon and have no shared history with them, won't he later switch to his current status i.e., Legend and thus work with them together to get out of the state?

Comment: The point is that he would be out of place in their illusion...they wouldn't know who he is....that's what I meant by [***anachronism***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/anachronism)

Comment: Okay, but we saw Sara meet Roy for the first time and eventually they all realise what was going for they remembered everything of their real lives; this is my point: even though Rory would be somewhat out of the context in the shared hallucination, they would eventually all remember who actually they are.